# Android: TextView with an address - click on address to redirect to Google Maps

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

So I am trying to figure out a way that when a user clicks on the address in a textview, that they will be redirected to Google Maps with that address entered. I kept looking around and I saw that people suggest using **android:clickable="true"** but it is not working. I suppose I can add a click listener but what if I have other text in my textivew such as phone number and then I want to click on the phone number to input the number to be dialed? This is what I have so far and it is not working:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/viewTitle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/fragment_title_background"
        android:padding="@dimen/borderSize"
        android:text="Contact"
        android:textColor="@color/White"
        android:textSize="@dimen/fragment_title_text_size"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:clickable="true" />
```

Comment: "I kept looking around and I saw that people suggest using but it is not working." Suggest using what?

Comment: Ah sorry. My mistake. It was the android:clickable property

Comment: @aegean, below, has pretty much the right answer. You will need a click listener. You will also need separate TextViews for the different information you are displaying if you want different actions for the clicks (unless you want to figure out the action based on the location of the click, but that seems like a giant pain)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I suppose I can add a click listener but what if I have other text in
>   my textivew such as phone number and then I want to click on the phone
>   number to input the number to be dialed?

You can add a clickListener to your address textView(which is for address) and a **different** clickListener to your other textView(which is for phone number). If user clicks into address textView you can redirect to mapView, and redirect to dialing if phone number editText is clicked.

Comment: Thank you. I will have to redo the method for getting the data so I can separate my addresses and phone numbers as separate textviews.